# Phonegap - Delete contacts makes my app no work more

Tags: cordova, contacts

I developed a simple phonegap app to manage contacts.

This part list all the contacts and with a button, when this is clicked, delete the contact. Everything works fine but when I delete one contact succesfully, I want to reload my web to see the new list without the contacts deleted but my app don't load correctly.

I have no idea what the problem could be...

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // specify contact search criteria
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter = "";      // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple = true;  // return multiple results
        filter = ["displayName","phoneNumbers"]; // return contact.displayName field    displayName

        // find contacts
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {

      for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
        //window.alert("ID = " + contacts[i].id);
        document.write(contacts[i].displayName);
        tel = contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
        if (tel== null){
document.write("Sense telefon");
        }else{
                for (j=0;j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length;j++) {
            if (contacts[i].phoneNumbers != null &&
contacts[i].phoneNumbers != 'undefined') {
                document.write(" "+contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value);
            }
        }
        }
        //document.write('<button id='+i+' onClick="reply_click(this.id,contacts);">Borrar</button>');
        var button = document.createElement("button"); 
        button.id = i; 
        button.onclick = function() { reply_click(this.id, contacts); }; // append button to DOM
        document.body.appendChild(button);
        document.write(contacts[i].id);
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    };

    function reply_click(clicked_id,contacts)
    {

        window.alert(clicked_id);
        window.alert(contacts);
         for (i=0;i<contacts.length;i++) {
         if(i==clicked_id){
         try{
            persona = contacts[i];
            persona.remove(onRemoveSuccess,onRemoveError);
            window.alert("Contacte Borrat");
            setTimeout("location.href='buscacont.html'", 5000);
            }catch(err){
            window.alert(err);
            }
            }
         }

    }
    function onError(contactError) {
        window.alert('onError!');
    }
    function onRemoveSuccess(contacts) {
         window.alert("Removal Success");
    }

    // onRemoveError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onRemoveError(contactError) {
         window.alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
    }


    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Find Contacts</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The logs didn't say anything usefull.

**EDIT: ADDITTIONAL INFO**

My other page has this code, it have a different structure:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {

    //function prova(){

    //}
    /*
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
        myContact.note = "This contact has a note.";
        console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
        app.receivedEvent('contactcreated');
        myContact.save(app.onContactSaveSuccess,app.onContactSaveError);
        */
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event

    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    onContactSaveSuccess: function(contact) {
        window.alert("Save Success");
    },
    onContactSaveError: function(contact) {
        window.alert("Save Failed");
    },

};

function doFunction(){
window.alert("Saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaave Success");
var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test LELO"});
        myContact.note = "This contact has a note.";
        console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);
        app.receivedEvent('contactcreated');
        myContact.save(app.onContactSaveSuccess,app.onContactSaveError);
        window.alert("Saaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaave Success");
}

function creaContacte()
{
var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
var txt = "";
  nom = x.elements[0].value;
  num= x.elements[1].value;
  email= x.elements[2].value;

        var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": nom});
        myContact.note = "Contacte creat amb MarcGarciaContactManager";
        myContact.name = nom;

        var phoneNumbers = [];
        phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('General', num, true);
        myContact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;


        var emails = [];
        emails[0] = new ContactField('General', email, true);
        myContact.emails = emails;

        console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", note: " + myContact.note);

        myContact.save(app.onContactSaveSuccess,app.onContactSaveError);
        window.alert("Contact creat");

}
function buscacon()
{
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="pepepe"; 
        var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }

    // onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
    //
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            window.alert("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
        }
    }

    // onError: Failed to get the contacts
    //
    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    }


}
```

It's a simple code to add contacts, the html part i didn't add it because is a simple form and a javascript call function...

The strange is that when I run the app..... If first create a contact using this page, after I can check all the time without problems the other page (the page to see al the contacts), but if I check first the page to see al the contacts, this crashes the second time I visit it (not load properly the deviceready or whatever..)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `ondeviceready` event is not fired the second time.
Change the code like this. 
Remove the `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` line and add it back in a function called `onLoad` (or what you want):

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

Then, change `<body>` with `<body onload="onLoad()">`.

The code listed above is taken from the [official documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready).

This should work because

> Any event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its callback function called immediately.

So, even if the `deviceready` event was already fired and it's not fired again the second time, in this way the callback is called anyway.